# SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services users get error permissions are insufficient rsAccess

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, permissions

I am running SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services on one server, and accessing data on another SQL Server 2012. I can publish and run reports myself, both locally on the server and remotely from my desktop. Other users get access denied, even though they are set up as both system admins for site settings on the report server and as Report Builders, Content Managers, etc for the folder with the reports in it (in other words, I have given them the most permissions I can, and they still cannot access the site).

I have tried applying these permissions to a group, and when that didn't work, I applied them to single users. They appear to have the same permissions as I do, but nothing is working for them.  I have read many posts on this error, most of which say to do the things I have already done and re-done. I am missing something, obviously.

Report Server Service account is Network Service. The Report Server database credential is NT Authority\Network Service. I don't know if that is important or not. I am a local admin on the server. Thanks for any help!

Comment: update: if i make one of the users a local admin on the report server, access is granted. not an optimal solution, obviously, but maybe a hint?

Comment: one other possibly useful bit of information: the dataset uses a SQL Server logon to access the data on the second SQL Server, not Windows Authentication.

Comment: How are the data sources setup on the report server? I would setup an database user per database for read only access. Then you can use this account in the data source.

Comment: data source uses a sql server login with read only (denydatawriter).  if i can get to the report, it runs every time with this access. it's getting the user to the report that is not working. it seems to be some issue with the reporting site itself, not the report. i hope this helps clarify.

Comment: Do the users have both `Browser` and `NavigateFolder` permissions in the folder?

Comment: users have every folder permission i see: browser, content manager, my reports, publisher and report builder (just in the hopes one of them would work). i don't see navigate folder listed.

Comment: What is the error message the user gets? Have you checked the log files on the report server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured it out. i had not noticed the "folder settings" on the home page. i had set permissions on the project folder, but not the home folder. the documents i read talked about the system admin/user level, and setting permissions for roles on folders, and discussed specifically clicking the drop down arrow next to the folders to set those.

so the main folder needs its own settings, and it is in a different spot. thanks!